# How to add a custom program to "Open With" list of programs in Xubuntu 13.04? How to associate a file with a program to open it with?

Tags: xubuntu, file-association

[How to associate file types with Sublime Text 2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204004/how-to-associate-file-types-with-sublime-text-2I) have downloaded Sublime Text 2. I've unpacked it in `/opt/Sublime Text 2/` directory.

Now I want to open all `.conf` files with ST2. But I can't set this easily. Xubuntu doesn't offer ST2 in the list of `Open With` programs.

I do:

right-click on the `fonts.conf` >>  `Properties...` >> `Open With` >> `Other Application`.

And an `Open With` window appears. And it doesn't have ST2 application.

How either to add ST2 to the `Open With` list or how to associate a file with ST2?

**UPD**:

Similar questions and are not answered:

[associate program to a file where program is not in list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230823/associate-program-to-a-file-where-program-is-not-in-list)

[How to associate file types with Sublime Text 2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204004/how-to-associate-file-types-with-sublime-text-2)

why are simple things getting hard in Ubuntu (Xubuntu)?

Comment: Very similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115113/change-all-associations-from-gedit-to-another-application/115117#115117

Comment: Good article on adding programs to the "open with" list at [https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/ubuntu-fix-add-program-to-list-of-applications-in-open-with-when-right-clicking-files-in-nautilus/#comment-2353]

Comment: See a better answer by IraGainesUK [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2032083)

Comment: To open all files with given program I have defined custom dialog command using `nautilus-actions`, so I have something like "Open with NotepadQQ"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this way. And without any command line typing, which is good.

1. In "**File Manager**" right click on a file (e.g. `file.conf`) you want to be opened by Sublime Text 2 (or any other application).
2. Choose "**Properties**". A window titled `file.conf - Properties` should appear.
3. In its tab "**General**" click "**Open With:**" and then choose "**Other Application...**". A window titled `Open With` should appear.
4. At the bottom of this window select "**Use a custom command:**" option and then "**Browse...**".
5. Browse to the necessary executable, Sublime Text 2, for example.

The most important part now: before click `Ok` put the selected path into double quotes, e.g.:

```
"/opt/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text"
```

because otherwise it cannot accept the path .

Comment: I don't have the option user a custom command :(

Comment: "Use a custom command" was removed some time ago, I believe before GNOME 3.0.

Comment: I suspect the quotes are needed only because there's a space in the path.

Comment: Still not possible with ubuntu 17. Possible with ubuntu 7.

Answer (score 31):

Read this answer: [How to associate file types with Wine in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270344/how-to-associate-file-types-with-wine-in-nautilus).

You must create/edit a `.desktop` file located in `~/.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications/`

Locate the `Exec=` parameter and at the end of the line add `%U` - it will be replaced with the filename to be opened.

Also see [Associating file types in Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361446/associating-file-types-in-ubuntu-13-10/364592#364592).

Comment: You can add %f to the end of the line instead of %U. Example: Exec=ProgramName %f

Comment: Working on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've just tried:

1. Go to `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications/`
2. Create a new file `appName.desktop` (`appName` is the name of the app you want to use)
3. Copy content of any other *.desktop file (I used `gedit.desktop`)
4. Update the content: `Name =` , `Exec =` , ..., with `%U` being the filename to be opened.
5. Save it.
6. Right click on the file you want to be opened with the `appName`
7. Go to Properties/Open With and click on 'Show Other applications'
   8  Your appName should be there, just select it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer worked for me:
[Globally associate file type with certain application](https://askubuntu.com/a/538596/298983)

1. Download and install deb file for sublime text Eg: from https://www.sublimetext.com/3
2. After installation Check that file sublime_text.desktop exists in /usr/share/applications/
3. Fire terminal and type:

   $ sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
   Add the following lines at the end:
   [Default Applications]

   : (some existing association mappings)

   [Added Associations]

   : (some existing association mappings)

   text/plain=sublime_text.desktop;

   Save and Exit.

This file overrides the /etc/gnome/defaults.list, so all file association goes in to mimeapps.list file.

Comment: It's an answer to a different question. Each time you want to add sublime as owner of a file extension, you have to re-do this hacking. The proper answer is to add a /usr/share/applications/*.desktop file, such that whenever you want to open a file with Sublime, it'll be an option in the open file dialog.