# Globally associate file type with certain application

Tags: 14.04, file-association, file-type

I don't need "Ubuntu-tweak" and i know about GUI method of associating certain files with certain applications using right click and "Open with". I am having problem setting filetype association globally in a file:

```
/usr/share/gnome/applications/defaults.list
```

E.g.:

```
image/x-psd=gimp.desktop
```

If i want to open all PSD's in a photoshop, i have created photoshop.desktop file and placed it under `/usr/share/applications`. Now when i press Super (windows) key and type Photoshop i see that icon, but i can't:

1. drag'n'drop that on my desktop. How can i do that?
2. if i change `image/x-psd=gimp.desktop` to `image/x-psd=photoshop.desktop` it still opens in a gimp. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question has been answered here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/540400/changing-default-app-for-pdf

Answer (score 14):

Solved my issue myself.

File `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` are overriden by `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, so all file association goes in to `mimeapps.list` file:

```
[Default Applications]
image/vnd.adobe.photoshop=wine-extension-8bs.desktop
```

In this example I've set to open `.psd` in a Photoshop through Wine. If I go in to `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` and add:

```
image/vnd.adobe.photoshop=gimp.desktop
```

It won't open `.psd` in a Gimp, because it got overriden by `mimeapps.list`. Spent few hours to figure that out lol.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Do you have a link to the documentation about `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` overriding `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` or where you found that information?

Answer (score 2):

Necromancing.
This is what worked for me:

added my desired application to /usr/share/applications.

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/bash.desktop
```

Copy-paste over from Terminal (gnome-terminal.desktop), and replace gnome-terminal with bash:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Bash
Comment=Use the command line
Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;bash;
TryExec=bash
Exec=bash
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
X-GNOME-DocPath=gnome-terminal/index.html
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=bash
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=BugBuddyBugs
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.18.3
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-SingleWindow=false
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Actions=New
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=bash

[Desktop Action New]
Name=New Shell
Exec=bash
OnlyShowIn=Unity
```

Now associate the application with shell-scripts.
To do so, edit mimeapps.list:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Add the following lines at the end (after all entries in section [Default Applications]):

```
[Added Associations]
application/x-shellscript=bash.desktop
```

Now in "File Manager" (aka nautilus), browse to one of the files you want to open. Choose "Properties". In the "open with"-tab, choose reset.

And voilà, Shell scripts will now be opened by bash, if you double-click with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can append `%U` in the `[Exec]` field.

Ex:`[Exec] = command %U`

When you open a file with *Open with*, application list show that application. Once opened it will be saved as default application.