# Why can't snap files be modified in any way?

Tags: permissions, snap, read-only

I have been trying for a long time to change Blender's icon, but no matter what I do, I am not allowed to edit anything in `/snap/blender-tpaw/3/`.

Here's what I tried:

- Editing the files from `nautilus` without `sudo`.
- Editing the files from `nautilus` with `sudo` (`sudo nautilus` in terminal ).
- Using terminal commands such as `cp` or `rm` without `sudo`.
- Using terminal commands with `sudo` (such as `sudo cp <source> /snap/blender-tpaw/3/` or `sudo rm /snap/blender-tpaw/3/<filename.ext>`)
- Doing everything above in a root terminal (using `sudo -i`)

In every case I get the following error:

```
cannot remove/copy '/snap/blender-tpaw/3/filename.ext': Read-only file system
```

where filename is the file and .ext is its extension.

This also applies to other snaps' files, not only Blender.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is it just impossible to change those files? Although I don't think it is impossible because everything here from Ubuntu to Blender is open-source, so they have no reason to block us from modifying those files.

**EDIT:**

I used Main Menu (alacarte) to change the icon, but I still want to know why I cannot modify any snap file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's impossible to change the contents of the snap without re-building the snap. This is primarily a security measure, to ensure that the snap hasn't been tampered with.

However, the icon referred to is likely in a desktop file called `blender-tpaw_blender.desktop` which *is* editable, and can be found in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`.

You could change the following line to update the icon:-

```
Icon=/snap/blender-tpaw/3/meta/gui/icon.svg
```

Comment: This "impossible to change" thing with snap is very - I mean, VERY - annoying!

The main reason I would like to use snap is that I want to make parallel installations of the same program (eg. Firefox) and then make experiments with the "copy" installation without messing up the main installation.

By the way, the change on the .desktop file didn't work in the case of Firefox.

Comment: It's not "impossible", it's just not how snap is designed. Snap files are SquashFS images -- they can be updated without using any snap-specific tools.

Answer (score 31):

While the premise of the question is technically correct (you can't change files of a snap), there are ways to work around this.

One such way is to use the `--bind` option in conjunction with `mount`, to remount the existing file hierarchy  to somewhere else.

For example, if you want your snaps to use the system certificates instead of the certificates installed in `core`, you can mount the directory containing the system certificates on the host *on top of* the system certificates directory in `core` with the following command:

```
sudo mount --bind -o nodev,ro /etc/ssl/certs /snap/core/current/etc/ssl/certs/
```

This doesn't actually change the snap filesystem. If you unmount the folder, the old folder will take its place:

```
sudo umount /snap/core/current/etc/ssl/certs
```

Note: Mounts do not persist between reboots. There are several ways to make mounts persist after a reboot. One such way is to create a `systemd` startup script:

```
$ cat <<-EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/snap-core-current-etc-ssl-certs.mount
[Unit]
Description=Mount unit to fix etc ssl certs in core package
After=snapd.service

[Mount]
What=/etc/ssl/certs
Where=/snap/core/current/etc/ssl/certs
Type=none
Options=bind,nodev,ro

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
$ systemctl enable snap-core-current-etc-ssl-certs.mount
```

Taken from [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/certificate-substitution-and-snaps/1077/6).

Comment: Great solution, thanks v. much!  Just one niggle: newer systemd versions (the one on 18.04 as of this writing) no longer accept mounts atop paths that contain soft-links; thankfully the above config could be replaced with a line in `/etc/fstab`, eg: `echo -e "/etc/ssl/certs\t/snap/core/current/etc/ssl/certs\tnone\tbind,nodev,ro\t0 2" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab` -- [source](https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/2407)

Comment: Very helpful update @sxc731, thanks! Some small improvements to this `/etc/fstab` approach: add `x-systemd.after=snapd.service` to the mount options, like the mount unit did, so `systemd` waits for the `snapd` mounts, and change the trailing `2` to `0` (it's a bind mount, after all). The final command would be: `echo -e "/etc/ssl/certs\t/snap/core/current/etc/ssl/certs\tnone\tbind,nodev,ro,x-systemd.after=snapd.service\t0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab`

Answer (score 3):

Actually it *is* possible to unpack edit and run snap using `snap try` command. Here is example for Microstack:

```bash
# Remove existing installation:
sudo snap remove --purge microstack

# download and unpack tree
mkdir ~/snap-repo
cd ~/snap-repo
snap download microstack --beta
mkdir ~/snap-tree
cd ~/snap-tree
sudo unsquashfs ../snap-repo/microstack_245.snap
```

Now you can freely edit files under `~/snap-tree/squashfs-root`.
When you are ready you can run snap with those changes using:

```bash
sudo snap try ~/snap-tree/squashfs-root/

snap list microstack

Name        Version  Rev  Tracking  Publisher  Notes
microstack  ussuri   x1   -         -          try
```

When finished you can run `snap remove PACKAGE` as usual.

Reference: https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-try

Comment: Quick and easy!