# Mount /snap as RW in 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Tags: mount, 18.04, snap

I installed PyPy3 via `sudo snap install` and when I'm installing packages, I get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/snap/pypy3/2/site-packages/easy_install.py'
```

I tried finding the mount point and remounting with `sudo mount -o rw,remount` but to no avail:

```
mount: /snap/pypy3/2: cannot remount /dev/loop11 read-write, is write-protected.
```

I want to mount some directories under `/snap` as RW.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why snap files cannot be modified in any way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919091/why-snap-files-cannot-be-modified-in-any-way)

Answer (score 0):

The underlaying snap filesystem (squashfs) is purely read only and cannot be made writable. Perhaps the pypy3 snap needs some love to redirect site packages to $SNAP_USER_DATA where it would be fully writable.