# How can I add a command-line option to a favourited application?

Tags: command-line, snap, ubuntu-gnome, find, spotify

I have a 4k display, so by default Spotify is incredibly zoomed out. To fix this, I had a look at [this post](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Linux-client-barely-usable-on-HiDPI-displays/td-p/1067272), which recommends adding a command line option. This works when I launch Spotify through the terminal, however I want it to launch that way by default when I click on the icon. I attemped to follow the guidance in the rest of the solution, which mentions editing `spotify.desktop`, however whenever I try to edit it gedit says the file is read-only, even using `sudo`. First, I used `sudo find . -name spotify.desktop` and got the response of:

```
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
./snap/spotify/21/meta/gui/spotify.desktop
./snap/spotify/21/usr/share/spotify/spotify.desktop
find: ‘./proc/19908/task/19908/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘./proc/19908/net’: Invalid argument
```

Running `sudo gedit /snap/spotify/21/meta/gui/spotify.desktop` or `sudo gedit /snap/spotify/21/usr/share/spotify/spotify.desktop` opens gedit, but in read-only mode. Attempts to change the file permissions leads to `chmod: changing permissions of '/snap/spotify/21/usr/share/spotify/': Read-only file system`.

How should I best proceed?

Comment: Related: [Why can snap files not be modified in any way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919091/why-can-snap-files-not-be-modified-in-any-way)

Comment: @steeldriver Amazing, thank you: that resolves my issue!