# Unable to delete read only file system in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: read-only

```
root@cd:~# sudo find / -iname 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/8039/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/8039/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/mysql': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/8039/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/mysqladmin': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/7917/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/7917/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/mysql': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core/7917/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/mysqladmin': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core18/1265/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core18/1223/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql': Read-only file system
```

Comment: I don't actually see a question in your post (heading aren't always visible when page is opened; so heading info should be repeated).  A RO (read-only) file system usually means an error occurred which needs to be investigated; it's made read-only to prevent data loss with messages thrown to logs giving clues as to why. You need to scan logs, possibly reboot & `fsck` your file-system - ie. normal system maintenance.

Comment: Related: [Why can snap files not be modified in any way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919091/why-can-snap-files-not-be-modified-in-any-way)

Answer (score 1):

This is a snap based on its location. Snaps are sandboxed and the proper way to remove them is to do a `sudo snap remove mysql`

Answer (score 0):

snaps are all mounted read-only.

Check this command:

```
mtodorov@efk:~$ mount | grep snaps
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/hello_20.snap on /snap/hello/20 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_88.snap on /snap/canonical-livepatch/88 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/hello_38.snap on /snap/hello/38 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_8039.snap on /snap/core/8039 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_90.snap on /snap/canonical-livepatch/90 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_7917.snap on /snap/core/7917 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
mtodorov@efk:~$
```

As you see, all snaps have first option **`ro`** among **`(ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)`** mount options, which is a shorthand for "read-only".

Hope this helps.