# Getting write permission for /snap

Tags: permissions, snap

How can I get the write permission for the files residing under `/snap` directory which is created by snap v.2.44?
I cannot do that even with root access and also there isn't any group named `snap` in `/etc/group` to enable me to add my user to it to gain any special privilege.
Also when I want to `chmod` the files I get this error :

```
Read-only filesystem
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/919098/590937