# Unable to move a file from one location to another

Tags: lubuntu, 22.04, root, pcmanfm-qt

I'm running a copy of Lubuntu 22.04 on an old Dell Inspiron 531s.

I'm trying to get a file from the Desktop into the location shown in the image below, even though pcmanfm-qt has been opened as a "root instance." This instance was opened using the instructions in the page linked to below...

https://www.mycomputertips.co.uk/113

Moving a file from the desktop to a file manager that has been opened as root has never been an issue before with previous distributions of Lubuntu. Can someone show me how to get this file moved successfully? I would appreciate it! Please ask if you need additional information. Thank you for your time! :-)

[image: error message]

Comment: Related: [Why can't snap files be modified in any way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919091/why-cant-snap-files-be-modified-in-any-way)

Comment: Snaps are *squashfs* and mounted RO by design, so they cannot be altered/corrupted in any way; with no change in 22.04 from prior releases.  What you're attempting to do is intentionally blocked to prevent accidental or purposeful corruption to the files.  Your approach is wrong; you don't need to write into /snap/ to change configs for `firefox` if that's what you're trying to do - but what you're trying to do is in my opinion unclear  (user directories of firefox are in `~/snap/firefox/` not `/snap/firefox/`

Comment: Thank you, steeldriver and guiverc! That answers my question. I guess I'll have to approach this problem another way, Lord willing. I appreciate your help! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using the instructions in the page linked to below, praise and thanks to God! :-)

https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/

After purging the Firefox snap package and installing the .deb version of Firefox, I then was able to bring up the file manager as a root instance again and move the file in question to the desired folder. :-)