# Fancy bookmarks in pdf readers

Tags: evince, adobe-reader, foxitreader

**Foxit reader** allows you to create new bookmarks and also set style properties

[image]

With **Evince**, you can view bookmarks without style, you can't create new ones

[image]

With **Adobe Reader 9**, you can view long bookmarks, but can't create bookmarks

[image]

I am looking for a pdf reader/editor which allows you to create fancy bookmarks and also view long bookmark names without having to enlarge the bookmarks panel. Such task can be done by Adobe Acrobat Pro, but it is not supported by Ubuntu anymore.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. This is the only thing that I need to permanently stay in Linux, any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Use adobe if that is what you like - https://askubuntu.com/questions/767937/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-in-ubuntu-16-04/805399

Comment: Thank you, but that is Adobe Reader, doesn't support pdf editing. I would need the pay version Adobe Acrobat Pro, that can't be installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: So use the reader for bookmarks and any of the numerous alternates for editing. The pay version, if you have it, may run in wine, not sure.

Comment: Yeah, the only thing that annoys me is that I cannot set Adobe Reader as default application

Comment: Why not ? see https://askubuntu.com/questions/540400/changing-default-app-for-pdf