# Firefox: open .pdf files with acrordrdc (installed by snap)

Tags: 20.04, firefox, adobe-acrobat

I'm trying to open `.pdf` files in `Firefox` with `acrordrdc` installed via snap. I tried:

1. Since `acrordrdc file.pdf` works I tried using a "wrapper" file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   acrordrdc $1
   ```
2. Editing the `acrordrdc.desktop` (see [Changing default app for PDF](https://askubuntu.com/a/1168551/802536)).

In the first case (the wrapper solution) acrordrdc opens with an empty window. No file is showed.

In the second case I can select "Acrobat Reader DC" in `Firefox` but nothing happens when the files is downloaded. Acrobat is not opened.

**Edit.** After the N0rbert answer I tried to modify my wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp $i ~/Downloads/renamed.pdf
acrordrdc ~/Downloads/renamed.pdf
```

and now it works. Now I need to find a way to remove the file(s) after I read it (them).

I don't understand why I need to rename it. If I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp $i ~/Downloads/$1
acrordrdc ~/Downloads/$1
```

it doesn't work. The file is copied but not opened.

Comment: The `acrordrdc` snap is Wine-based. So there may exist some specifics with file-associations. Did you tried to open the PDF file from file-manager by right click on it and selecting *Open With* → *Adobe Acrobat Reader DC* ? Is it working normally?

Comment: @N0rbert I just tried. It works normally.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and desktop?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 with Mate. I installed Ubuntu Classic + ubuntu-mate-desktop

Comment: I tried to prepare the answer on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS, but `acrordrdc` acts weird here. I'll check the Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS and report results.

Comment: I did some research and summarized it in below answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging in Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS I discovered that Firefox copies PDF file of interest to the `/tmp` folder.

The `/tmp` folder can't be accessed by this snapped application. Wrapper script does not help either. So it is impossible to integrate `/snap/bin/acrordrdc` with Firefox.

I'll recommend to remove snapped version of Adobe Acrobat with

```
snap remove acrordrdc
```

and install native pretty old deb-based version of Adobe Reader 9.5.5 by:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo apt-get install ./AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatk-adaptor:i386
```

and then choose it in the Firefox settings.

Comment: I edited my question after you answer. Unfortunatly I need a more updated version of acrobat reader. Installing AR 9.5.5 is not a solution.

Comment: I think `snap connect acrordrdc:removable-media` should also work.

Comment: @Kulfy, no - it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get a wrapper to work. It has to do these steps:

1. If no argument given, call acrordrdc and exit.
2. If the target file (“$1”) is not located below /home, copy it to a location in your home directory and change the target name.
3. Convert the target name to DOS (eg. Z:\home\msohnius\tmp\file.pdf).
4. Call acrordrdc with this new argument.