# acrordrdc (wine) doesn't open files in /tmp dir

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I installed `acrordrdc` via snap on `Ubuntu 20.04` with `Mate` desktop manager. I found that `acrordrdc` can't open files in the `/tmp` directory. This is related with a previous question: [Firefox: open .pdf files with acrordrdc (installed by snap)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1263008/802536)

If I try

```
acrordrdc /tmp/file.pdf
```

it doesn't work. Why? Can it be fixed?