# Add open with VS Code to context menu in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, visual-studio-code

In windows, we have an option: adding "Open with code" action to context menu, this allows us to open any file or folder with VS Code.

Is there any way to add this feature in Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Globally associate file type with certain application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538299/globally-associate-file-type-with-certain-application)

Answer (score 46):

Run

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/harry-cpp/code-nautilus/master/install.sh | bash
```

Just run this in your terminal, and it will add open with VS Code in context menu for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Edit: Works as well for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, 20.10 and 22.04 LTS.

**Source**: [harry-cpp's GitHub Repository](https://github.com/harry-cpp/code-nautilus)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 as well

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 20.10 too

Comment: On my distro (Pop!_OS 20.10) I had to install the `python3-nautilus` package in order to get it to work. You can do that with `sudo apt install python3-nautilus`.

Comment: Make sure to close all open windows first. Works great!

Comment: Pop!_OS now also seems to add `python3-nautilus` so the manual step is no longer required

Comment: isn't there a way that you don't have to run a script that you don't know what has inside

Comment: @Sahin There's a way to see what's inside the script, you can go to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cra0zy/code-nautilus/master/install.sh`

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 21.10. Note that the repo has now been renamed to https://github.com/harry-cpp/code-nautilus (although the old link still redirects there)

Comment: this worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04. thanks!

Comment: Also working on **Ubuntu 22.04**

Answer (score 8):

What you need to do is install  **Nautilus Actions**

> *`sudo apt install nautilus-actions`*

and add new action :

Path: `code`
Parameters: `%B`

[image: command]

[image: in menu]

**NOTE** ❗ ❗ 
 Modern version of Nautilus Actions (nautilus-actions package in trusty (14.04 LTS), xenial (16.04 LTS), artful (17.10)) are named as FileManager Actions (filemanager-actions package, it is not yet packaged in Debian and Ubuntu - [see at repology.org](https://repology.org/metapackage/filemanager-actions/versions)).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions

sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions-nautilus-extension
```

**NOTE 2**
As of Ubuntu 19.04, the package is filemanager-actions.

```
sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions
```

orginal post [askubuntu.com/a/1031746/843203](http://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/843203)

Comment: "Package nautilus-actions is not available, but is referred to by another package.  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source"

Comment: @MichaelCole Sorry !  Modern version of Nautilus Actions (nautilus-actions package in trusty (14.04 LTS), xenial (16.04 LTS), artful (17.10)) are named as FileManager Actions (filemanager-actions package, it is not yet packaged in Debian and Ubuntu - see at repology.org). 

** sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions **

sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions-nautilus-extension

orginal post https://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/843203

Comment: where can I find the vscode icon to set it to this context-menu?

Comment: This might be a long shot but... when opening vscode with right click actions from filemanager action, it does not import all of the bashrc $PATH. For example, if I right click for 'Open with Code' and try to debug a javacript file, vscode will say it can not find Node.js. However, when I open vscode normally, full $PATH is exported and can then debug javascript normally. Any idea why the right click aciton is missing $PATH export?

Answer (score 6):

If you're on 20.10 and you're running this script:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cra0zy/code-nautilus/master/install.sh | bash`
```

You'll need to install `python3-nautilus` because `python-nautilus` isn't in non-LTS versions of Ubuntu.

Simply install the python3 version of python-nautilus

`sudo apt install python3-nautilus`

Then restart nautilus (this will close all nautilus folders)

`nautilus -q && nautilus &`

And it should work.

Comment: The last command did it for me. Also, python3-nautilus wasn't found, so I installed python-nautilus instead.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find this vscode extension for nautilus written by [Crazy0](https://gist.github.com/cra0zy/f8ec780e16201f81ccd5234856546414) that lets you do this.

The steps can be found in that github gist, which are:

1. Go to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/cra0zy/f8ec780e16201f81ccd5234856546414).
2. And do the following (also found in the head section of that gist):

   - Place me in `~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/`, restrart Nautilus, and enjoy :)
   - `mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions && cp -f VSCodeExtension.py ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/VSCodeExtension.py && nautilus -q`

Just tested on Ubuntu Bionic and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

1.Create a file *~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/open-in-code.sh* with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" ]; then
    set $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        destination="$1"
    else
        zenity --error --title="Error - Open in Visual Studio Code" \
        --text="You can only select one file/directory."
        exit 1
    fi
else
    destination="`echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI" | sed 's/^file:\/\///'`"
fi

# It's only possible to go to local directories
if [ -n "`echo "$destination" | grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9]\+:'`" ]; then
    zenity --error --title="Error - Open in Visual Studio Code" \
    --text="Only local directories can be used."
    exit 1
fi

exec code "$destination"
```

2.Add execution permission to the file:

```
 $ chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/open-in-code.sh
```

3.Restart Nautilius.

4.Right-click on a file or directory, you will see this:

[image: open in nautilus]

**Source**: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto

Answer (score 0):

Just Run this command on your terminal:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cra0zy/code-nautilus/master/install.sh | bash
```

Source: [itectec.com](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-add-open-with-vscode-to-context-menu-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: I would not suggest that anyone pipe a script from the internet directly into your shell.  [It's dangerous.](https://sysdig.com/blog/friends-dont-let-friends-curl-bash/)

Comment: The same answer does exist

Answer (score 0):

also if you use VSCodium you can install my version of "python3-nautilus"

run

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akifkadioglu/codium-nautilus/master/install.sh | bash
```

thank you [Harry](https://github.com/harry-cpp)