# multiple 'open with' applications in right-click context menu with nautilus/filemanager-actions?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, nautilus-actions

I would really like to get the old Gnome behavior restored, where you could right-click, hover over Open With... and then a submenu with a list of applications would open - something like this:

[image: right-click-hover]

[Have multiple 'open with' applications in context menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073839/have-multiple-open-with-applications-in-context-menu) implies it can be done with `nautilus-actions`, which are now renamed and I installed as in [Nautilus-actions in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030940/nautilus-actions-in-18-04) ; now I can run `fma-config-tool`.

I found some generic explanations on how nautilus-actions works, like:

- [How do I customize the context menu in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353610/add-a-new-nautilus-context-menu-action-without-using-nautilus-actions
- [Add open with vscode to context menu in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049111/add-open-with-vscode-to-context-menu-in-ubuntu)

... but I cannot really figure out, what do I need to do, so I can add additional entry, say "Open With...", which when hovered, will give me a submenu with the same applications as in the screenshot above - depending on the file type of the selected and right-clicked type. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Any progress with this?