# How to add "Open in Code" for a folder in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, visual-studio-code, context-menu

I want to know is there a way to add an option "Open in VS Code" for Right Clicking a folder in Ubuntu 20 (Focal Fossa). I know its possible for a file using Nautilus but is it possible for a folder?

[image: context_menu_screenshot]

Comment: Since you're using `20.04`, you can use the `filemanager-actions` package. Check the following answer for more details https://askubuntu.com/a/1257070/8698. This package seems to have been removed from later versions with no replacements. I did find a project on [GitHub](https://github.com/bassmanitram/actions-for-nautilus) that is supposed to be a replacement for it. I offer no guarantees, however, as I've never used it myself and I've just found it after searching for it for this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add open with vscode to context menu in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049111/add-open-with-vscode-to-context-menu-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Add `inode/directory;` to the `.desktop` launcher of the application to have it also appear in the right-click "Open with other application" item for a folder.