# .desktop opening in text editor rather than as an executable

Tags: .desktop

I don't know if I did something wrong, but all my `.desktop` files open in text editor. I have tried to install `f.lux`, there is a `setup.py` file, which also opens in some text editor.

I have tried to change the location of the files to `.local/share/applications`, check if they had permission to run as program, I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`.desktop` files are text files, and thus are designed to open in your text editor. They only function to launch applications when placed in their specific context, i.e., when placed in `/usr/share/applications`, `.local/share/applications`, autostart folders etc. When placed on the Desktop (i.e. in the "Desktop" folder), they can be set to act as program launchers.

Still, if you wish, you [could associate .desktop files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538299/globally-associate-file-type-with-certain-application) to be opened with `gtk-launch` (installed by default in standard Ubuntu, see [this Askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal)) or `dex` (available in the software repository).