# 22.04 SVG "open with another application" not working with InkScape

Tags: nautilus, 22.04, filemanager, inkscape, svg

I have latest Inkscape 1.2.1 (2ed6d7ae0b, 2022-08-22, custom), installed via snap, on up-to-date fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04

Open Inkscape and then menu 'File / Open...' works fine. But if in Ubuntu File manager I right-click a SVG file and select Inkscape via "Open with another application" nothing at all happens. Selecting other apps instead (e.g. Gedit) no problem.

Anyone know how to fix this?

And whether this  is an Ubuntu-related issues or rather an Inkscape bug? In the latter case I will search their issue tracker and file a bug if I can't find anything related.

Comment: Would [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538299/globally-associate-file-type-with-certain-application) help?  Perhaps it isn't being set properly during installation.  I'm not sure who you can report it to, though.  Probably people who made the Inkscape snap.

Comment: Thank you, @Ray but I will keep the Image viewer as the default app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is (yet another) limitation of the current implementation of Snap. The connectors are set properly, so Inkscape, once loaded, has access to visible files in your home directory. However, the confined shell in which the application is started does *not* see your home directory. Thus, the path to your file passed to the program points to file that does not exist in that shell.

There is nothing you can do thus far. An [issue about this](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/3649) has been filed with Inkscape.

Either you have to adapt your workflow for the time being. Alternatively:

- You can replace the Snap version by the regular APT version. The APT version may be less recent than the Snap version.
- You can install the AppImage
- You can enable Flatpak on your system and install the Flatpak, which does not have the issue (but then, it has by default access to all your system files, so there goes the sandbox).

Comment: +1 Adapting workflow is easier for some folks, and how to adapt workflow may be worth expanding in the answer.

Comment: I [installed Inkscape 1.2.1](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.2.1/gnulinux/ubuntu/ppa/) via APT, and can confirm that that solves the problem. I also added a [comment](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/3649#note_1085635805) to the Gitlab issue. Thank you @vanadium

Comment: I still have this issue with Inkscape 1.2.2 (732a01da63, 2022-12-09, custom) on Ubuntu 22.04. The inkspace link on the menu has the following line as command: env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/inkscape_inkscape.desktop /snap/bin/inkscape %F