Unable to launch java applications normally
I have installed OpenJDK 21, When I click on .jar file to open it refuses to open and when I go to 'Open With' it doesn't show OpenJDK 21 and when I try to add it to list it doesn't let me. I'm only able to launch it threw terminal.
java -jar /home/matthew/Downloads/TechnicLauncher.jar
Execute permission is on allowed as well.

OpenJDK 21 is sth different from OpenJDK 11. Is your "Technic Launcher" build against that version? Both versions are more or less incompatible

It runs when I use terminal to run it. So I assume it isn't a compatibility issue.

This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/317392/how-to-add-a-custom-program-to-open-with-list-of-programs-in-xubuntu-13-04-ho

@amar Thank you that worked I appreciate your help!
